# Low-cost 532nm DPSS laser modulation

Tags: laser, experimental-technology

Could anyone suggest modern means of modulating 100mW CW 532nm DPSS laser? This should be low-cost(<50$) in high volume.

Frequency bandwidth is 10Mhz, so modulation of pumping diode would obviously not work (due to relatively long fluorescence of Nd:YAG)

**Update**: Anyone had experience with MEMS modulators? (difractive e.t.c)

Comment: Do you need a resonant modulator (i.e. modulating one fixed frequency) or a broadband modulator (DC-10MHz)?

Comment: @CuriousOne "broadband", DC-10Mhz, random digital data.

Comment: OK... ouch. The only thing I can think off, right now, is to convert the temporal modulation into a spatial one, e.g. with a rotating mirror setup. That would allow the use of a "slow" spatial modulator like a micro-mirror array followed by a second rotating mirror to convert back into the time domain... but that has plenty of problems and the cost will probably still not be nowhere satisfactory.

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind for such high speeds is an AOM or EOM. In lab settings, these cost quite a lot, but AOMs are used in things like laser printers, so maybe in bulk, and without nice packaging, you can have them for cheap. 

At significantly lower speeds, a liquid-crystal modulator would work, and are not so expensive as the a/eoms

Otherwise, I have to say that your constraints are very demanding.

Comment: @Eion As a side note, I recently realized that common EOM (Pockels Cells) have quite high switch energy due to high voltage and intrinsic capacitance. This makes it dissipate 10-450W of power on 10Mhz depending on aperture... They typically designed to switch fast, but only few 1000's of times per second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it really obvious that modulating the pumping diode won't work? It's not obvious to me. You say that the fluorescence lifetime of Nd:YAG is slow, but you are thinking of the lifetime when there is no stimulated emission. If there *is* stimulated emission, excited atoms can be de-excited very very quickly.

Think a little harder about laser dynamics, especially [gain clamping](http://www.rp-photonics.com/gain_clamping.html) and its consequences. I think you'll find that if you are pumping well above the laser threshold, the gain medium's fluorescence lifetime doesn't really matter. It is true that there will be a *little* bit of light emission after you turn the pump off, but probably so little that it won't matter for most applications. The Q-factor of the cavity (related to how reflective the mirrors are) would probably make a bigger difference for modulation rate.

But I could be wrong. :-D